# Forms Not Appearing

Tags: python, django

I'm following the following tutorial to learn how to create a Django form. I'm really stuck on why the form isn't appearing on the designated html page.

Here's my code:

**reviews/url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.review_list, name='review_list'),
    url(r'^review/(?P<review_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
    url(r'^wine/$', views.wine_list, name='wine_list'),
    url(r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.wine_detail, name='wine_detail'),
    url(r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$', views.add_review, name='add_review')]
```

**reviews/Forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from reviews.models import Review

class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('user_name', 'rating', 'content')
        widgets = {
            'content': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 15})
        }
```

**reviews/Views.py:**

```
# View that provides wine information and reviews
def wine_detail(request, wine_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, pk=wine_id)
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_detail.html', {'wine': wine})

# View that contains add review form
def add_review(request, wine_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, pk=wine_id)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        # Retrieves values entered
        rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
        content = form.cleaned_data['content']
        user_name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']

        review = Review()
        review.wine = wine
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.rating = rating
        review.content = content
        review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        review.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reviews:wine_detail', args=(wine.id,)))

    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_detail.html', {'wine': wine, 'form': form})
```

**Template**

```
<h2>{{ wine.name }}</h2>
<h5>{{ wine.review_set.count }} reviews ({{ wine.average_rating | floatformat }} average rating)</h5>

<h3>Recent reviews</h3>

{% if wine.review_set.all %}
<div>
    {% for review in wine.review_set.all %}
    <div>
        <em>{{ review.content }}</em>
        <h6>Rated {{ review.rating }} of 5 by {{ review.user_name }}</h6>
        <h5>
            <a href="{% url 'reviews:review_detail' review.id %}">
                Read more </a>
        </h5>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}

<h3>Add your review</h3>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'reviews:add_review' wine.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

**Here's a screenshot of now:**

[image: Contains the html page with the console]

Clearly you can see that the form element is being generated without the input forms. I'm thinking that {{ form.as_p }} could be wrong. I'm not sure why though. I've checked the syntax, and I'm not finding any errors that would cause the form to be missing. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

**Here's what it should look like:**
[image]

Comment: Try removing the colon in the template file name: `'reviews:/wine_detail.html'`.

Comment: Tried removing the colon. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Please post your project directory structure and your `settings.py`. Also, what do you see when you view the HTML source on the browser? Can you see the form tags, submit tag, and CSRF token, or do you see nothing?

Comment: Not sure how directory structure and settings.py would help fix the issue. I just posted a screenshot with the html element in the Chrome inspector.

Comment: Something about {{ form.as_p }} not be read properly

Comment: Part of the purpose of using a ModelForm is so that you can just say `form.save()` rather than extracting the form's info and manually building a model the way you are.

Comment: i think that `class ReviewForm(ModelForm):` should be `class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):`

Comment: I believe you are trying to browse to another view and not `add_review`. Please post the source to that view too.

Comment: One thing is, you are trying to do `request.POST` whether it is get or post. So try something like this: `form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None)` - or even `if request.method == "POST": `

Comment: @all found my dumb mistake ... my url for the form was pointed to a different address at r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$' whereas I was trying to figure out why it was missing on  r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/'